# Is gaming on Mac OS X possible?

Tags: windows, imac, games

I'm currently thinking about buying a 27" iMac after my current Windows computer. I know Mac OS X is awesome, but I was wondering how is gaming on this OS. What I mean is, how much of the current game releases are both on Windows and Mac OS X ? And if they are not released on Mac OS X, is it possible (performance speaking) to play them on the Windows VM ?

I know my question might not be clear. If that is so, please comment, and tell me what I explained wrong, and I'll try to improve it.

Thanks

Comment: You can still use Boot Camp.

Comment: Do you target specific game types?

Comment: I'm a big League Of Legends player, and I like other MMO from times to times. I have preordered Star Wars : The Old Republic too

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! This question is really to vague to be useful and answerable. If you have a specific question about compatibility, like "Does *some brand* make Mac-compatible games", feel free to ask. Please take a look at the [FAQs](http://apple.stackexchange.com/faq) for more info. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I hate to disappoint you but I am afraid gaming on a mac is still very limited. 
Head to [steampowered.com](http://steampowered.com) and see for your self.

Although I believe that in the near future the major gaming publishers will see the opportunity with growing numbers of mac users and reconsider adding OS X as a platform for gaming.

Using a virtual machine is not recommended for gaming.
You can dual boot though and run Windows natively and games work fine this way. See [Boot Camp](http://www.apple.com/support/bootcamp/)

Comment: Yeah indeed the Apple section on Steam is really limited, and there are few "popular" games. I'll check your link on boot camp

Comment: Boot Camp is great; I had a 20" iMac from the first release of the aluminum body style (late 2007 / early 2008?), so not an incredible powerhouse. Running Win XP under Boot Camp I played the likes of Oblivion and Bioshock (both new at the time) with graphics cranked up, both ran beautifully.

Answer (score 1):

Deus Ex does not work in VM. However every other game I've tried worked fine. Starcraft, Total War, Paradox titles, psp emulator, and some others.

Negligible native mac releases, don't count on them.

Answer (score 0):

it's definitely possible! Though not all games are well supported on the Mac.

Some games which i have played on the mac:

- Games from Apple's App store (requires Lion OS)
- Blizzard games (World of warcraft, Starcraft 2, Warcraft 3)
- Found a link that's pretty good for your reference
  http://mac.appstorm.net/roundups/games/the-giant-list-of-50-mac-games/

Comment: You could include some specifics about games that are or are not well-supported to improve this answer.